# How to extract series of words separated by commas and start and end words?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Given this sort of text,

```
this_txt <- "Blah blah blah particular phrase this guy, this other guy, that guy, that other guy, or something else blah blah blah, blah blah. Blah blah blah, blah; and so blah."
```

I need to extract "this guy, this other guy, that guy, that other guy, something else"

So, I need to tell regex to match any sequence of words occurring between any one of the following:

two commas

a "particular phrase" and a comma

a comma and an "or"

an "or" and a space

I'd be content with a solution that includes a few undesired words, if that is the most that can be asked of regex.

I'd imagine the code would look something like this (which doesn't run because I am a total regex noob):

```
this_txt <- "Blah blah blah particular phrase this guy, this other guy, that guy, that other guy, or something else blah blah blah, blah blah. Blah blah blah, blah; and so blah."
this_pattern <- "^.*\\b(particular phrase|,|or)\\W(\\w+\\W+)+\\W(,|or).*$"
gsub(this_pattern, "\\2", this_txt, ignore.case = T)
```

EDIT:

I am getting closer with this (which does run):

```
  this_txt <- "Blah blah blah particular phrase this guy, this other guy, that guy, that other guy, or something else blah blah blah, blah blah. Blah blah blah, blah; and so blah."
  this_pattern <- "^.*\\b(particular phrase)\\W+(.*)\\W+(,|or).*$"
  gsub(this_pattern, "\\2", this_txt, ignore.case = T)
#[1] "this guy, this other guy, that guy, that other guy,"
```

But how to include the last item "something else"?

Comment: Is the expected result a list of character vectors or  a single character vector?

Comment: Either one is fine.

Comment: Sorry, but how to get `something else`? The rules you have are not at all clear. I can only get `something else blah blah blah`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, based on *"an "or" and a space"*, wouldn't it be just `something`?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, that would also match just `this` and not `this guy`, etc. if we follow that rule. Something is inconsistent about this `something else`. I get all other matches without problems.

Comment: I disagree about `this guy`: that's between `particular phrase` and a comma, so all of it should be extracted. The `something` vs `something else` is due to the use of whitespace as a delimiter.

Comment: I've been toying with this a bit, and I think that tokenizing it might be more appropriate than trying regexes to solve the problem. That is, find the positions of each `,`, `or`, `particular phrase`, etc, and set up rules such that `,` must go to another `,`, `or` must go to a ` ` (space), etc. You'll have to loop it (`while` with some creative index tracking), but I suggest singular regexes will take you from [99 to 100 problems](https://xkcd.com/1171/).

Comment: I can only suggest [this](https://ideone.com/klWOfH) that yields `[1] "this guy"       "this other guy" "that guy"       "that other guy"
[5] "something"` with `this_pattern <- "\\bor\\s*\\K\\S+|(?:\\bparticular phrase\\b|,(?!\\s*\\b(?:particular phrase|or)\\b))\\s*+\\K[^,.]*(?=,)"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest you may get with the current requirements:

```
(?:\bparticular phrase\b|\bor\b|,)\s*\b(?!or\b)(\w+(?:[^,.\w]+\w+)*?)(?=\s*(?:,|\bor\b))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lTLeqx/1/)

**Details**

- `(?:\bparticular phrase\b|\bor\b|,)` - a whole word `or` or `particular phrase`, or a comma
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!or\b)` - the next word cannot be `or`
- `(\w+(?:[^,.\w]+\w+)*?)` - Group 1:

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `(?:[^,.\w]+\w+)*?` - 0+ repetitions, as few as possible, of

    - `[^,.\w]+` - 1+ chars other than comma, dot or word chars
    - `\w+`  - 1+ word chars
- `(?=\s*(?:,|\bor\b))` - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ whitespaces and a comma after them or a word `or` immediately after the current position.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/1EVJmI):

```
pattern <- "(?:\\bparticular phrase\\b|\\bor\\b|,)\\s*\\b(?!or\\b)\\K\\w+(?:[^,.\\w]+\\w+)*(?=\\s*,|\\bor\\b)"
this_txt <- "Blah blah blah particular phrase this guy, this other guy, that guy, that other guy, or something else blah blah blah, blah blah. Blah blah blah, blah; and so blah."
regmatches(this_txt, gregexpr(pattern, this_txt, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE))[[1]]
```

Output:

```
[1] "this guy"                      "this other guy"               
[3] "that guy"                      "that other guy"               
[5] "something else blah blah blah"
```